# Не могу разбить массив на тестовый и тренировочный

Tags: массивы, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd

cc_apps = pd.read_csv("datasets/cc_approvals.data", header=None)

cc_apps = cc_apps.replace('?', np.NaN)
cc_apps.fillna(cc_apps.mean(), inplace=True)
cc_apps.isnull().sum()



for col in cc_apps:

    if cc_apps[col].dtypes == 'object':
         cc_apps = cc_apps.fillna(cc_apps[col].value_counts().index[0])
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
for col in cc_apps:
    if cc_apps[col].dtypes=='object':
       cc_apps[col]=le.fit(cc_apps[col])


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

''' Drop the features 11 and 13 and convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array''' 

cc_apps = cc_apps.drop([11,13], axis=1)
cc_apps = cc_apps.values

X,y = cc_apps[:,13] , cc_apps[13,:]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                y,
                                test_size=0.33,
                                random_state=42)
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

> ```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-9-fff2e4c9c001> in <module>()
>       3 
>       4 # Drop the features 11 and 13 and convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array
> ----> 5 cc_apps = cc_apps.drop([11,13], axis=1)
>       6 cc_apps = cc_apps.values
>       7 
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'drop'
> ```

Comment: текст ошибки достаточно очевидный - `cc_apps` - объект типа Numpy NDArray, у которого нет метода `.drop()` Как вы получили / прочитали `cc_apps`?

Comment: можете выложить `cc_approvals.data` на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://github.com/Oysiyl/DataCamp_Solutions_Python/tree/master/Predicting%20Credit%20Card%20Approvals/datasets

Comment: ошибка не воспроизводится если запустить ваш код. Уточните суть вопроса

Answer (score 1):

чтобы избавиться от ненужных столбцов в Numpy NDArray можно воспольозваться [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

Исходная матрица:

```
In [67]: np.random.seed(123)

In [68]: data = np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 14))

In [69]: data
Out[69]:
array([[66, 92, 98, 17, 83, 57, 86, 97, 96, 47, 73, 32, 46, 96],
       [25, 83, 78, 36, 96, 80, 68, 49, 55, 67,  2, 84, 39, 66],
       [84, 47, 61, 48,  7, 99, 92, 52, 97, 85, 94, 27, 34, 97],
       [76, 40,  3, 69, 64, 75, 34, 58, 10, 22, 77, 18, 15, 27],
       [30, 52, 70, 26, 80,  6, 14, 75, 54, 71,  1, 43, 58, 55],
       [25, 50, 84, 56, 49, 12, 18, 81,  1, 51, 44, 48, 56, 91],
       [49, 86,  3, 67, 11, 21, 89, 98,  3, 11,  3, 94,  6,  9],
       [87, 14, 83, 70, 12, 54, 27, 38, 17, 61, 74, 99, 99, 65],
       [47, 16,  5, 86, 46, 15, 59, 40, 25, 45, 49,  0, 35, 29],
       [ 1, 83, 68, 30,  7, 93, 60, 65, 76, 67, 44, 51,  7, 88]])

In [70]: data.shape
Out[70]: (10, 14)
```

выбираем нжные столбцы:

```
In [71]: X = data[:, np.r_[:11, 12]]

In [72]: y = data[:, 13]
```

результат:

```
In [73]: X
Out[73]:
array([[66, 92, 98, 17, 83, 57, 86, 97, 96, 47, 73, 46],
       [25, 83, 78, 36, 96, 80, 68, 49, 55, 67,  2, 39],
       [84, 47, 61, 48,  7, 99, 92, 52, 97, 85, 94, 34],
       [76, 40,  3, 69, 64, 75, 34, 58, 10, 22, 77, 15],
       [30, 52, 70, 26, 80,  6, 14, 75, 54, 71,  1, 58],
       [25, 50, 84, 56, 49, 12, 18, 81,  1, 51, 44, 56],
       [49, 86,  3, 67, 11, 21, 89, 98,  3, 11,  3,  6],
       [87, 14, 83, 70, 12, 54, 27, 38, 17, 61, 74, 99],
       [47, 16,  5, 86, 46, 15, 59, 40, 25, 45, 49, 35],
       [ 1, 83, 68, 30,  7, 93, 60, 65, 76, 67, 44,  7]])

In [74]: y
Out[74]: array([96, 66, 97, 27, 55, 91,  9, 65, 29, 88])

In [75]: X.shape
Out[75]: (10, 12)
```